# Change the CharField to TextField

Tags: django, django-models

I want convert one of my field type from CharField to TextField

I changed as followings:

```
From:
project = models.CharField('Project',max_length=500)        

To:
project = models.TextField('Project',blank=True)
```

And after I run the migrate cmd , I met the following errors:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'project' used in key specification without a key length")
```

I performed the steps mentioned in
[Django: Convert CharField to TextField with data intact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863155/django-convert-charfield-to-textfield-with-data-intact)

```
MySQL:
BEGIN;
    ALTER TABLE TestLog
        MODIFY failed_reqs TEXT NULL,
        MODIFY passed_reqs TEXT NULL;
COMMIT;
```

Bug met the same errors:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE ct_task
    -> MODIFY project TEXT NULL;
ERROR 1170 (42000): BLOB/TEXT column 'project' used in key specification without a key length
```

Anyone can help how can i do this conversion ? many thanks

Comment: This question has some nice explanation why this error happens. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827063/mysql-error-key-specification-without-a-key-length. Is `project` field has unique constraints or is it used as  index?

Comment: thanks Sagar ， as you mentioned ，the project field has unique constraints ， after I removed the constraints ， it works well now ， many thanks :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)